# Is it possible to compute the wavelet transform of a unit step function?

Tags: wavelet

Is it possible to find theoretically the continuous or discrete wavelet transform of a unit step function (consntly 0 for t<0 and constantly 1 for t>=0) or of a function starting from zero and approaching 1 in a finite time? I just wonder if this is possible because these signals don't have a finite energy. Thanks. E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a mundane way: normaly yes, because wavelets can be "blind" to a locally-constant signal, especially when the number of discontinuity points are finite.
Finite energy (square integrable) or finite action (integrable) functions is a class of choice, but wavelet transforms can exists in more generic cases of functional spaces.

Here is a simple generic proof. For the continuous case: let us call $H(t)$ the Heaviside step function. Then $|H(t)\psi(t)|$ is dominated by $|\psi(t)|$. In other words,

$$|H(t)\psi(t)| \le |\psi(t)|\,.$$
By virtue of the [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), if $\psi(t)$ is $L_1$ or integrable (in addition to being  $L_2$), then  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(t)\psi(\frac{t-a}{b})\mathrm{d}t$ is well-defined. Moreover, since admissible wavelets have zero-average, the continuous wavelet coefficients can decay at infinity. With wavelets of finite support, they will be zero for all $\psi(\frac{t-a}{b})$ and $b>0$ with support in $[a,\;+\infty[$.

For discrete wavelets, this would be about the same. As long as the filters are summable (or $\ell_1$), and this happens  especially for FIR wavelet filters, you can compute coefficients. Special note: if a discrete filter is $\ell_1$, then it is $\ell_2$ as well, so the condition is milder than in the continuous case.